# How can I go about learning to output audio to a speaker using a STM32 board?

Tags: amplifier, audio, stm32, i2s

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I am trying to learn how to output audio on a STM32 board. The board I have is the STM32F746ZG **NUCLEO** board.

I have small (1-3) second audio files I have stored on the internal flash of my STM32, so there is no external SD card or anything. They have 16 bit data @44.1kHz. I was able to convert to 8bit so I tried both 8 and 16 bit. I plan to output the audio to a PAM8302a amplifier which is connected to a speaker. I was following along with the AN3126 (Waveform generation using DAC). I was able to successfully generate waveforms and view them on my oscilloscope. But when I send audio data, it's just static. I tried to follow along [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D2iXQy6DzbY) video, but it just sounds like static for the most part with a hint of sound in the background. Not sure what I'm doing wrong but I feel this is not the way to go about this.

So does anyone know what I should be using on the board or reading on? I see SAI, I2S, SPI, etc and honestly just don't know where to start. Am I missing components? I'm not interested in filtering and what not at the moment, that's something I feel can come after. I just want to at least be able to output something audible for now.

Thanks

Edit: For the comments asking for the sine wav

```
uint8_t samples = 100;
void getSineVal(){ 
    for(int i = 0; i < samples; i++){
        sineVal[i] = (sin(2*i*PI/samples)+1)*((0xFFF+1)/2);
    }
}
getSineVal();
HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim6);
HAL_DAC_Start(&hdac, DAC_CHANNEL_1);
HAL_DAC_Start_DMA(&hdac, DAC_CHANNEL_1, sineVal, 100, DAC_ALIGN_12B_R);
// sineVal being the data, 100 being the # of data points
```

The clock for TIM6 is at 80Mhz. The prescalar is 80-1, the period is 100-1, and the #samples is 100. So 80Mhz/(80 * 100 * 100) = 100Hz.
Here is the picture of the sine wave I generated at 100 Hz

[image: Capture showing a 3V 100Hz sine wave. The peaks are slightly clipped, but otherwise it looks fine.]

Edit 2: Here is the code I made.

```
uint8_t *p = (uint8_t *)&audioArray;
... // I didn't paste here but I move the pointer to the data section
      if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_13) == GPIO_PIN_SET){
          uint16_t *pp = (uint16_t *)p;
          uint32_t wavBuffer1[512];
          uint32_t wavBuffer2[512];
          flg_dma_done = 1;
          int count = 65536;
          while(count > 0){
              for(int i = 0; i < 512; i++){
                  wavBuffer2[i] = *pp;
                  pp++;
              }
              while(!flg_dma_done){ // check if the flag is done
                  __NOP();
              }
              flg_dma_done = 0; // clear/reset the flag
              count = count - 512; // 512 bytes decrease
              HAL_DAC_Stop_DMA(&hdac, DAC_CHANNEL_1); // Stop the transfer
              HAL_DAC_Start_DMA(&hdac, DAC_CHANNEL_1, (uint32_t*)wavBuffer2, 512, DAC_ALIGN_12B_R); // Start transmission
              for(int i = 0; i < 512; i++){
                  wavBuffer1[i] = pp;
                  pp++;
              }
              while(!flg_dma_done){ // check if the flag is done
                  __NOP();
              }
              flg_dma_done = 0; // Clear/reset the flag
              count = count - 512;
              HAL_DAC_Stop_DMA(&hdac, DAC_CHANNEL_1); // Stop the transfer
              HAL_DAC_Start_DMA(&hdac, DAC_CHANNEL_1, (uint32_t*)wavBuffer1, 512, DAC_ALIGN_12B_R); // Start transmission
          }
      }
...
void HAL_DAC_ConvCpltCallbackCh1(DAC_HandleTypeDef* hdac)
{
    flg_dma_done = 1;
}
```

Here is an image of the schematic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9z4m.jpg (Everytime I try to post an image using the image function here, it never works)

Comment: How did  you truncate 16 to 12 bits?  In the right order?

Comment: So how did you connect the two boards? Where is the code?

Comment: I'm not really looking for any bug fixing really, I'm just asking any suggested readings or what to read on doing this. T

As for the "code", per AN3126 I have the DMA output going to the A+ on the audio amp, and the set up was straight forward for the DMA output. I just configured the clock and had a sine value function generate values and sent it to the DMA with a HAL function. I tried then doing that with the audio data instead of the sine wave but I believe it's not that simple.

Comment: Generate a sinewave (like 100Hz or 1 kHz) audio file, plot its waveform out from the DAC on a scope, and add that pic to the question. Basic stuff like confusing offset binary with 2's complement format sounds a LOT like static and this will help diagnose...

Comment: @user_1818839 I updated the post, and just decided to include the code as someone asked. Keep in mind I can hear the sine wave audio tone fine on the board when I tried a 441Hz wave.

Comment: If you can generate such clean sine wave, I think the problem is how it is connected to PAM8302, so how is it connected? Is it a bare chip or some module? Any schematics or wiring diagrams? What supply voltage you use?

Comment: Sinewave is clipping slightly so the analog side isn't perfect, but 90% or so of that amplitude should be fine. You've eliminated a lot of the problem areas. If it's as clean after the PAm8302, the amp is probably connected OK. Can you do the same via a WAV file? You are converting to offset binary explicitly in the getSineval function, (+1, *full scale/2) but we still don't know how your WAV file reader handles the format.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the delay in a response, I've had a busy week. Anyways, I've added code and a schematic in the post. Anyways, I've added new code I made. When I press the button on my board to run the section, I hear like two sections of some sound but it's basically garble.